# How to make a destination navigable from multiple different destinations?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

Say I have a screen which is used a few times in the navigation graph. Like the following:

There are two tabs in the bottom navigation bar: items and favorites. The items destination displays a list of items. The favorites destination displays the list of items the user has favorited. Clicking on an item in both screens opens up a Item Details destination.

```
+---------+        +------------+
|  Items  | -----> |Item Details|
+---------+        +------------+

+---------+        +------------+
|Favorites| -----> |Item Details|
+---------+        +------------+
```

Do I make one Item Details destination and two actions going into it or two Item Details destinations? Which one is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use one

> Item Details

- This way you don't have to maintain two fragments that are exactly the same
- Your project will be easier to read

So one Item Details destination and two actions is better.

Answer (score 0):

Use [global action](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-global-action) for this(item details). Create one item details destination and one global action, that's it.